# Create an empty PixelArray with V8 / node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, html5-canvas, v8

I'd like to be able to make an empty PixelArray to compare with output from [node-canvas](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas) from within JavaScript.

For example:

```
var cleanData = new PixelArray ( 20 );
```

Is this possible? Am I on the wrong version of Node.js? (0.8.3)

Comment: Did it work when you tried it?

Comment: No it is considered undefined (`PixelArray`)

Comment: I have also tried this approach using node-canvas, to the same result:

    var Canvas = require('canvas');
    var PixelArray = Canvas.CanvasPixelArray;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Uint8ClampedArray** works.

```
var cleanData = new Uint8ClampedArray( width * height * 4 );
```

Some background:

http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/#7.1  Uint8ClampedArray is defined in order to replace CanvasPixelArray. It behaves identically to the other typed array views, except that the setters and constructor use clamping [WEBIDL] rather than modulo arithmetic when converting incoming number values.